# flickr api authentication without user intervention

Tags: api, oauth, flickr

I would like to programmatically query the Flickr API using my own credentials only just to grab some data from there on a frequent basis.  It appears that the Flickr API is favouring OAuth now.
My question is: how should I authenticate the API without user intervention just for myself?  Is it possible any more?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have received an oauth_token (Access Token), you can use it for multiple subsequent API calls.  You should be able to persist the token in a data store (I haven't done this myself) and use it even after your application restarts.  Of course, you still need to write the code to get the Access Token the first time.

If your application is already coded using the old authentication API, it looks like there is a one-time call that you can make to get a new-style Access Token.  See http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html#transition

Even if you don't have a coded application, you might be able to use the API Explorer for any of the calls that requires authentication ([flickr.activity.userComments](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.activity.userComments), for example) to harvest an api_sig and auth_token.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario which you are describing is sometimes referred to as 2-legged OAuth. (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) 
Google APIs support this via a 'service account'.

Unfortunately Flickr doesn't seem to support this kind of interaction.

For public data interaction (like downloading your public photos (photostream) from your account), there's no need to authenticate. You can get the data using only the Flickr user-id.

For other interactions (like downloading private photos (camera roll) from your account), you'll need to follow the full OAuth procedure at least once.